# Plot a histogram with normal curve and name the bins in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

Hi all, I am trying to plot the following type of plot using seaborn with a different data set. The problem is when a histogram type is used, I cannot name the bins (like 2-2.5,2.5-3..etc) even though it provides kernel curves. Bar plots  dont have function to draw the normal curve like in the picture. The image seems to be used SPSS statistical package which I have little knowledge of.

Following is the closest thing I can get (I have attached the code)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['1-1.5', '1.5-2', '2-2.5','2.5-3','3-3.5','3.5-4','4-4.5','4.5-5'],'val': [0,0,1,7,7,33,17,10]})
ax = sns.barplot(y = 'val', x = 'cat', 
              data = df)
ax.set(xlabel='Categories', ylabel='Frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So I guess the question you are asking is "How do I plot a histogram with KDE if I already have the accumulated data in bins?" That would be easy if you already have the 'normal curve' available. Otherwise, what would that curve be?

Comment: Actually the normal curved doesn't mean the perfect bell shaped one here. It could be skewed depending on the data. (in this case it definitely skewed and not normal). yes the question should be changed as you suggested and that's exactly the question I asks . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is of course that you don't have the original data, but data that has already been binned. One could reverse this binning and start with an array of raw data. Then perform the histogramming again and use a `sns.distplot` which, by default, shows a KDE plot as well.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cat = ['1-1.5', '1.5-2', '2-2.5','2.5-3','3-3.5','3.5-4','4-4.5','4.5-5']
val = [0,0,1,7,7,33,17,10]
data = []
for i in range(len(cat)):
    data.extend([1.25+i*0.5]*val[i])
bins = np.arange(1,5.5, 0.5)

ax = sns.distplot(data, bins=bins, hist_kws= dict(edgecolor="k"))
ax.set(xlabel='Categories', ylabel='Frequency')
ax.set_xticks(bins[:-1]+0.25)
ax.set_xticklabels(cat)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Use the `bw` keyword argument to the KDE function to set the smoothness of the curve. E.g. `sns.distplot(data, bins=bins, kde_kws=dict(bw=0.5), hist_kws= dict(edgecolor="k"))` where `bw=0.5` produces

[image]

Also try `bw=0.1`, `bw=0.25`, `bw=0.35` and `bw=2` to see the differences.

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for. I think, for the size of the data set, its ok to have the smoothness property 0.5 otherwise the curve is very abnormal or can we say overfitted ?