# create violin (kde) plot from sampled PDF (python)

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn

I need to create a series of violin (kde) plots, but I don't have sampled data, I have quantized values of the pdf.  The actual samples if enumerated would be too large and blow up memory.

So I already have e.g., 

`[0, 1, 2] << data values
[0.1, 0.4, 0.2] << pmf corresponding to these data values
or
[0, 10, 2] << counts corresponding to these data values`

I don't think scipy.gaussian_kde or any of the seaborn functions will accept this sort of input, which is a shame since they must use this form (data values, counts) as an intermediate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487220/plot-a-histogram-with-normal-curve-and-name-the-bins-in-seaborn) and it's answer?

Comment: "they must use this form (data values, counts) as an intermediate." I'm not clear on exactly what you have in mind, but the `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` does not do any binning/counting.

Comment: I already have a histogram, I want to smooth it into a kde.  I guess I was mistakenly assuming kde would first produce a histogram.  I can transform the histogram into a set of data samples representing it and feed that into the kde, but is there a better way?

Comment: No, the KDE is not just a smoothed histogram. There is information about it [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#kernel-density-estimaton) if you want to understand better how it works.